# Methods to speed up sha 512 hashing?

Tags: c, hash, openssl, sha

Through the use of openssl's sha 512 algorithm I'm currently able to calculate the hash of a 2GB file in between 3 - 3.3 seconds (my CPU is an i7-5820k) - including the time it takes to open, write to, and close files (open the input & write hash to text file).

I wondered if there are any known methods to speed this process up, or whether my HDD is entirely at fault, creating a bottleneck (Seagate BarraCuda Green 2TB 5900RPM SATA 6Gb/s 64MB Cache).

```
            FILE *ftest=fopen(hashInBuf, "rb");
            FILE *ftest2=fopen(hashOutBuf, "wt");
            //HASH FUNCTION
            SHA512_Init (&mdContext);
            while ((bytes = fread (data, 1, 1024, ftest)) != 0)
            SHA512_Update (&mdContext, data, bytes);
            SHA512_Final (c,&mdContext);
            for(i = 0; i < SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++){
              fprintf(ftest2, "%02x", c[i]);
              printf("%02x", c[i]);
```

(the code I'm currently using to calculate the sha 512)

Comment: How long does it take if you read the file and do not compute the hash?

Comment: Well, you can look at a HHD that runs at 7200 rpms or go to SSD.  But most likely in this senario, your HDD is the biggest bottle neck.  Although you don't list your processor either.

Comment: @EricPostpischil moving a 2GB file into the directory (and not computing the hash) took 0.000228 seconds... I'm supposing the HDD isn't the fault in this scenario.

Comment: @Deanie I did include it, just didn't declare it very obviously, I'll update my post - I've got an i7-5820k.

Comment: Optimization #1: Don't read 1024 bytes at a time.  Read an entire megabyte at a time.

Comment: Optimization #2: Have one thread performing the hashing while another thread is reading in the next several megabytes of data.

Comment: @selbie Those make a lot of sense actually thank you. I'll be honest though I've no clue how to implement the second optimisation you've suggested - is there a simple explanation / example or is this quite a complex procedure?

Comment: @JosephSmith: Moving a file from one directory to another does not move the data. It merely updates two directory entries. How long does it take if you read the file and do not compute the hash? (Just comment out the `SHA512_Update` call.)

Comment: `while ((bytes = fread (data, 1, 1024, ftest)) != 0)
            SHA512_Update (&mdContext, data, bytes);` is relevant to the speed issue.  The rest noise.  Try far larger buffers.

Comment: @EricPostpischil ah apologies. Having done what you stated the time is 0.94 seconds.

Comment: @chux Will give that a go, thank you.

Comment: Another option (on Unix and Linux) is to bypass stdio and use `open()` and `read()` with giving hints and prefetching from the file using `posix_fadvise()`.

Comment: If performance is crucial and you eliminated the IO bottleneck (btw., when your file is not cached in ram, reading a 2GB file from the harddisk you specified takes about 15-20 seconds!), then you can go for a OpenCL-capable GPU and do the hashing there. This will give you a _huge_ performance boost wrt the computational aspect.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Out of curiosity why does it seem that a hash computes even with SHA512_Update removed /commented out? Where does the value it produces come from?

Comment: @JosephSmith: Presumably you left in the initialize, the finalize, and the write. That would compute and write the hash of the empty string.